# Skipping Lines with Dashes in a text file with regex in c#

Tags: c#, parsing, text, text-files

I have a text file with SQL commands, I've done some code to "ignore" the comments and blank spaces in orde to get just the commands (I will post code below and a sample of the text file and output), that works fine but in that text file I also have lines such as this "-----------------------------------" that I need to ignore, I've done the code to ignore it but I can't figure out why it doesnt work properly.
Code:

```
 public string[] Parser(string caminho)
 {
            string text = File.ReadAllText(caminho);
            var Linha = Regex.Replace(text, @"\/\**?\*\/", " ");
            var Commands = Linha.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
               .Where(line => !Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^[\s\-]+$")) 
               .ToArray();
 }
```

This is the .Where I added to "ignore" the dashed lines:

> .Where(line => !Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^[\s-]+$"))

---

Sample of text with the dashes:

```
/

---------------------------------------------------------------------

UPDATE CDPREPORTSQL
SET COMANDOSQL_FROM =
'SELECT DESCONTO,EMPCOD,EMPDSC,LINVER,NOMESISTEMA,OBS,ORCCOD,ORCVER,PEDCOD,PEDDSC,
ROUND(PRCUNIT*#CAMBIO#,5) PRCUNIT,
ROUND(PRCUNITSEMDESC*#CAMBIO#,5) PRCUNITSEMDESC,
PROPCHECK,QTDGLOB,QTDPROP,REFCOD,REFDSC,EMPCODVER, COEFGERAL_PLT FROM #OWNER#.VW_PROPOSTAS', 
COMANDOSQL_WHERE = 
'WHERE ORCCOD=#ORCCOD# AND ORCVER=#ORCVER# AND NOMESISTEMA=#NOMESISTEMA# AND PEDCOD=#MYCOD#'
WHERE REPID = 'CDP0000057'
/

---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Sample of the output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------

UPDATE CDPREPORTSQL
SET COMANDOSQL_FROM =
'SELECT DESCONTO,EMPCOD,EMPDSC,LINVER,NOMESISTEMA,OBS,ORCCOD,ORCVER,PEDCOD,PEDDSC,
ROUND(PRCUNIT*#CAMBIO#,5) PRCUNIT,
ROUND(PRCUNITSEMDESC*#CAMBIO#,5) PRCUNITSEMDESC,
PROPCHECK,QTDGLOB,QTDPROP,REFCOD,REFDSC,EMPCODVER, COEFGERAL_PLT FROM #OWNER#.VW_PROPOSTAS', 
COMANDOSQL_WHERE = 
'WHERE ORCCOD=#ORCCOD# AND ORCVER=#ORCVER# AND NOMESISTEMA=#NOMESISTEMA# AND PEDCOD=#MYCOD#'
WHERE REPID = 'CDP0000057'


---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

These are the examples of statements that can occur and that I need to process:

```
/*    */
            UPDATE Orc 
/*UPDATE comando */
set MercadoInt = 'N', Coef_KrMo = 1, Coef_KrMt = 1, Coef_KrEq = 1, Coef_KrSb = 1, Coef_KrGb = 1, Coef_MDEmp = 1, Coef_MDLoc = 1, Abrv_MDLoc = '', Dsc_MDLoc = '', Arred_MDLoc = 'N', Arred_NDecs = 0 WHERE MercadoInt IS NULL
/
```

Another one:

```
/*    */
---- comment
            UPDATE Orc set MercadoInt = 'N', Coef_KrMo = 
             -1, Coef_KrMt = 1, Coef_KrEq = 1, Coef_KrSb = 1, Coef_KrGb = 1, Coef_MDEmp = 1, Coef_MDLoc = 1, Abrv_MDLoc = '', Dsc_MDLoc = '', Arred_MDLoc = 'N', Arred_NDecs = 0 WHERE MercadoInt IS NULL
/
```

And another one:

```
/*    */
            UPDATE Orc set MercadoInt = 'N', Coef_KrMo = 1, Coef_KrMt = 1, Coef_KrEq = 1, Coef_KrSb = 1, Coef_KrGb = 1, Coef_MDEmp = 1, Coef_MDLoc = 1, Abrv_MDLoc = '', Dsc_MDLoc = '', Arred_MDLoc = 'N', Arred_NDecs = 0 WHERE MercadoInt IS NULL
/
```

> Note that I need to process them even if there are commented section in the middle if the statement
> Note that everything else is working fine (it "ignores" the comments
> and blank spaces)
>
> The '/' is just to divide the commands in the text file

Comment: This can easily get more complex than a Regex will generally be able to cope with, if you need to do commenting in the same way as SQL does. E.g. a line containing dashes may be a perfectly valid piece of input, if it happens to occur as part of a multi-line string literal.

Comment: So ur saying that this method can prove ineffective in some cases?
What should be the best aproach without using third party software or add-ons?
Plus, for what I know the commands wont differ much from this

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever if  you need I can post a link to the full text file for you to take a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works on the examples you gave.

```
    private const string DashComment = @"(^|\s+)--.*(\n|$)";
    private const string SlashStarComment = @"\/\*.*?\*\/";
    private string[] CommandSplitter(string text)
    {
        // strip /* ... */ comments
        var strip1 = Regex.Replace(text, SlashStarComment, " ", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        var strip2 = Regex.Replace(strip1, DashComment, "\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        // split into individual commands separated by '/'
        var commands = strip2.Split(new[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        return commands.Where(line => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            .ToArray();
    }
```

I took the three examples you posted in your question and put them in a single string. It looks like this (yeah, it's ugly):

```
        private const string Test1 = @"/*    */
            UPDATE Orc 
/*UPDATE comando */
set MercadoInt = 'N', Coef_KrMo = 1, Coef_KrMt = 1, Coef_KrEq = 1, Coef_KrSb = 1, Coef_KrGb = 1, Coef_MDEmp = 1, Coef_MDLoc = 1, Abrv_MDLoc = '', Dsc_MDLoc = '', Arred_MDLoc = 'N', Arred_NDecs = 0 WHERE MercadoInt IS NULL
/
/*    */
---- comment
            UPDATE Orc set MercadoInt = 'N', Coef_KrMo = 
             -1, Coef_KrMt = 1, Coef_KrEq = 1, Coef_KrSb = 1, Coef_KrGb = 1, Coef_MDEmp = 1, Coef_MDLoc = 1, Abrv_MDLoc = '', Dsc_MDLoc = '', Arred_MDLoc = 'N', Arred_NDecs = 0 WHERE MercadoInt IS NULL
/
/*    */
            UPDATE Orc set MercadoInt = 'N', Coef_KrMo = 1, Coef_KrMt = 1, Coef_KrEq = 1, Coef_KrSb = 1, Coef_KrGb = 1, Coef_MDEmp = 1, Coef_MDLoc = 1, Abrv_MDLoc = '', Dsc_MDLoc = '', Arred_MDLoc = 'N', Arred_NDecs = 0 WHERE MercadoInt IS NULL
/";
```

Then, I called the `CommandSplitter`:

```
var result = CommandSplitter(Test1);
```

And output the results:

```
foreach (var t in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t);
    Console.WriteLine("////////////////////////");
}
```

That removed the `/* ... */` comments and the `-- ...` comments.

It also worked on this example:

```
    private const string Test2 =
        "Update Orc set /* this is a comment */ MercadoInt = 'N' -- this is another comment\n" +
        "Where MercadoInt is NULL --another comment";
```

The output:

```
Update Orc set   MercadoInt = 'N'
Where MercadoInt is NULL
```

**Update**
The code above returns an array of commands. Each command consists of multiple lines. If you want to remove extraneous spaces at the beginning of lines, and eliminate blank lines, then you have to process each individual command separately. So you'd want to extend the `CommandSplitter` like this:

```
private string[] CommandSplitter(string text)
{
    // strip /* ... */ comments
    var strip1 = Regex.Replace(text, SlashStarComment, " ", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    var strip2 = Regex.Replace(strip1, DashComment, "\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    // split into individual commands separated by '/'
    var commands = strip2.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    return commands.Select(cmd => cmd.Split(new[] {'\n'})
        .Select(l => l.Trim()))
        .Select(lines => string.Join("\n", lines.Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l))))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: they said that my code wouldn work because of situations where was some sections commented in the middle of the statement like this:

`UPDATE Orc set MercadoInt = 'N', Coef_KrMo = 
             -1, Coef_KrMt = 1, Coef_KrEq = 1, Coef_KrSb = 1, Coef_KrGb = 1, Coef_MDEmp = 1, Coef_MDLoc = 1, Abrv_MDLoc = '', Dsc_MDLoc = '', Arred_MDLoc = 'N', Arred_NDecs = 0 WHERE MercadoInt IS NULL`

Comment: Jim I will update my question with examples that they gave me to test, so If my dll can process the statements as so I think Im ok to go. Please refer to the edited question

Comment: wow awesome @JimMischel that outputs the entire statement without the comments right?

Comment: @Mr.Toxy: That's the idea, yes. Why not give it a try with your data?

Comment: ofcourse I will :) once I do I'll get back to you. hope it works thx

Comment: in the text file all the statements are divided by "/" in your code you divide the line after aplying the regex.

`var strip1 = Regex.Replace(text, SlashStarComment, " ", RegexOptions.Multiline);var strip2 = Regex.Replace(strip1, DashComment, "\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        // split into individual commands separated by '/'
        var lines = strip2.Split(new[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Shouldnt the `var lines = strip2.Split(new[] {'/'}, `be first and than run the commands through the regex?

Comment: Oh Ok I get it it's to work even if there are comments in the middled and that way it wont divide the text when encounters a / from a comment.

Comment: @Mr.Toxy: Exactly right. We get rid of the comments first, then split the individual commands on `/`. The reason it doesn't remove blank lines in the individual commands is because the first split isn't splitting on line endings. If you want to remove blank lines, then you need to go through the individual lines of each command.

Comment: but in your example you only pass one command at a time or am I wrong? I need to read all lines from the .txt and than parse them as you did

Comment: @Mr.Toxy: See my update, which removes blank lines and extraneous spaces.

Comment: thx for that update, I will test it out with the new changes, since I need to read from a text file, should I read line by line and feed each line to that process of regex or can I do something like this:


            `string text = File.ReadAllText(caminho);
            var strip1 = Regex.Replace(text, SlashStarComment, " ", RegexOptions.Multiline);`

etc... ??

Comment: How about `string text = File.ReadAllText(caminho)` followed by `string[] commands = CommandSplitter(text);` Seems like that'd be the easiest thing to do.

Comment: This functions requires me to read the commands from a text file.
Im asking if I do use it that way will it still work?

Answer (score 1):

All this seems rather complex and slow. If you just want to find/reject lines of dashes, why not use:

```
if (line.StartsWith("----"))
```

(Assuming that 4 dashes is sufficient to detect such lines unambiguously)

If there may be whitespace at the start of the line, then:

```
if (line.Trim().StartsWith("----"))
```

Not only is this approach infinitely more readable than regex, it'll most probably be much faster.

Comment: It's somewhat more complicated than that. There are two types of comments: those that start with `/*` and end with `*/` and can cover multiple lines (like C# block comments), and those that start with `--` and go to the end of the line (like C# `//` comments). He wants to strip both of them.

Comment: Finding /* and then skipping text until you hit a */ is a trivial parsing problem. As is finding // and truncating the current line. Although a regex can do these things, there are simpler approaches that will perform better. I prefer readable/maintainable code that performs fast to unreadable code that is slower. It's always worth asking the question, am I solving this problem the right way? (And it's ok for the answer to be yes sometimes and no other times, as long as we always ask the question of ourselves)

Comment: @JasonWilliams Jim is right I need to "ignore" both of those types of commants and the metho I choose also needs to work if a comment is in the middle of the statement such as SELECT Name, Age /,*E-mail, Adress*/ FROM tbl_Client WHERE....

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have a text file with multiple SQL commands, seperated by:

```
/

---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And you only want the text in between these dashes. If so, why not split the text with [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx), then get out all the elements?

[This](https://regex101.com/r/zJ4lC5/1) regex seems to work:

```
\/\n\n-+
```

Based on the Regex.Split documentation, the code would be:

```
string input = File.ReadAllText(caminho);
string pattern = "\/\n\n-+";            

string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
foreach (string match in substrings)
{
   //do cool stuff with your cool query
}
```

Comment: it's almost that xD I have the commands separated by '/' the dashed lines are just there for no reason. It wasnt me who has compiled this files and I cant change, I need to treat them as they are.
So summing things up the commands are divided by '/', the dashes are just rubish that needs to be ignored

Comment: You mean that the '/' are the separator that are always there, but the lines of ---- aren't always present? So there's also input like this? `/  sqlquery / sqlquery`

Comment: yes the '/' is the seperator and the lines of ----- aren't always there.
Here, Ill give you a link to the full text file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1xc1ft-s78NTHdZdlpTTWlfLVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Based on your document I agree with Damien that a Regex is not ideal in your situation. For me, there's too much differing text to make an effective regex. Plus, it looks pretty random how the dashes and backslashes are placed in your text, so a regex that might work on this specific file might not work on the next.

Comment: You're right but I have no Idea how to treat the file if I cant use anything aside VS and its default tools.
And if we assume that the files will all be almost like this?
Some dashed lines and comments but nothing that can interfere with the liability of this method? Without a sql parser dedicated to this as suggested above I can't see how can I improve this more

Comment: I just need some way to ignore the dashed lines, I've tried something like this: 
`.Where(line => line.Substring(line.IndexOf('-'),line.LastIndexOf('-')).Length < 1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex you could also use `!line.TrimStart().StartWith("-")` shoud be the same and I think it is faster.

Comment: I've tried something like this:  
`line.Substring(line.IndexOf('-'),line.LastIndexOf('-')).Length < 1`
But it doesnt work

Comment: does the split really work? becaus on the line above you replace the split character by " " - (I am no a regex expert)

Comment: yes the split really works here's a link to the output text file with the commands https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1xc1ft-s78NVWFtdi1YUXF3YXc/view?usp=sharing

> The file cant be opened in drive I dont know why, download it hence you can compare to the "old" file. You'll see that the split is working but the dashed lines using the code above are still outputed

Comment: Im thinking if I should post treat this after I get all commands and than run the array in a foreach and delete the ones that include this lines using ur suggestion

Answer (score -1):

I've done the code like this, so far is working good.

```
 public string[] Parser(string caminho)
        {
            List<string> Commands2 = new List<string>();
            string text = File.ReadAllText(caminho);
            var Linha = Regex.Replace(text, @"\/\**?\*\/", " ");
            var Commands = Linha.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
               .Where(line => !Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^[\s\-]+$")) 
               .ToArray();


            Commands2 = Commands.ToList();


          for(int idx = 0; idx < Commands2.Count; idx ++)
            {

                if (Commands2[idx].TrimStart().StartsWith("-"))
                {
                    string linha = Commands2[idx];
                    string linha2 = linha.Remove(linha.IndexOf('-'), linha.LastIndexOf('-') - 1);
                    Commands2[idx] = linha2;
                }



            }
          //test the output to a .txt file
            StreamWriter Comandos = new StreamWriter(Directory.GetParent(caminho).ToString() + "Out.txt", false);
            foreach (string linha in Commands2)
            {
                Comandos.Write(linha);
            }
            Comandos.Close();
            return Commands2.ToArray();
        }
```

> After they analyzed my code they said that I can't use this (As
>   mentioned above) because it wont work for some cases like comments in
>   the middle of the statements.
>   I will try now doing so using Tsql120Parser

Comment: If anyone has a method that works better than this one please say :D